# Is there a way to automatically enlarge pages up to one line if there would be a widow otherwise?

Tags: margins, page-breaking, widows-orphans

I use the `nowidow` package but it steals me so much space, therefore I would like to have something like a automized command `\enlargethispage{\baselineskip}` if there would be a single widow line on the next page otherwise.

Would be great if somebody had an idea how to do this!

Comment: No, but see the widows-and-orphans package, which warns of bad pages and so allows semi-automatic fixing.

Comment: TeX can both expand or shrink text to fit the page (look up glue).  One can adjust \parskip and/or \baselineskip to increase this ability.  Try `\parskip=0pt plus 1fil` (overkilll) or `\advance \baseilneskip by 0.5pt plus 0.5pt minus 0.5pt`